# Código Javascript com erro ao usar evento Keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-eventos

Estou utilizando o evento keyup para chamar uma função javascript, e assim formatar o conteúdo digitado dentro do meu input. 
No entanto, ele não funciona corretamente, conforme esperado.

A ideia é: colocar apenas a primeira letra em maiúsculo, as demais ele força minúsculas. Quando for palavra com apeundefinednas 2 caracteres, ele sempre configura em minúsculo.

O problema é que, ao pressionar a tecla de espaços dentro do input ou ao pressionar a tecla backspace dentro no input vazio, a função retorna a palavra "undefined" dentro do campo.

Estou também com dúvidas se deveria utilizar algum outro evento mais adequado para este caso.

Segue link do jsfiddle para que possam verificar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  function ajustaNome(text) {
    var loweredText = text.toLowerCase();
    var words = loweredText.split(" ");
    for (var a = 0; a < words.length; a++) {
      var w = words[a];

      var firstLetter = w[0];

      if (w.length > 2) {
        w = firstLetter.toUpperCase() + w.slice(1);
      } else {
        w = firstLetter + w.slice(1);
      }

      words[a] = w;
    }
    return words.join(" ");
  }
  $('#campo_nome_empresa').keyup(function() {

    var campo_nome_empresa = $("#campo_nome_empresa").val();
    var nomenome = ajustaNome(campo_nome_empresa);


    $("#campo_nome_empresa").val(nomenome);


  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Codigo para colocar apenas a primeira letra maiscula. Se a palavra tiver apenas duas letras, ela deverá continuar minúscula.<br><br> Exemplo, se a pessoa digitar:<br> - luis sanches de oliveira<br> - LUIS SANCHES DE LIVEIRA<br><br> o resultado será:<br>  - <b>Luis Sanches de Oliveira</b>
</p>

<input name="campo_nome_empresa" type="text" class="form-control input-md" id="campo_nome_empresa" maxlength="150">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4Ls16bu3/

Comment: "*funciona corretamente, conforme esperado*", qual era o esperado? Qual foi o comportamento inesperado que viu? Aqui ele deixou a primeira letra maiúscula quando digitei 3 letras. Não era isso que ele deveria fazer?

Comment: vou editar minha pergunta .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que você possui o valor `"luis "`, ao efetuar a divisão no espaço em branco, `loweredText.split(" ")`, você obterá o *array* `["luis", ""]`. O `undefined` aparece porque dentro do laço você acessa a posição 0 da palavra, mas `""` não possui a posição 0.

Neste caso, basta validar o tamanho da *string* obtida antes de fazer qualquer coisa:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  function ajustaNome(text) {
    var loweredText = text.toLowerCase();
    var words = loweredText.split(" ");
    
    for (var a = 0; a < words.length; a++) {
      var w = words[a];
      
      // Se for uma string vazia ignora
      if (w.length === 0) continue;

      var firstLetter = w[0];

      if (w.length > 2) {
        w = firstLetter.toUpperCase() + w.slice(1);
      } else {
        w = firstLetter + w.slice(1);
      }

      words[a] = w;
    }
    return words.join(" ");
  }
  $('#campo_nome_empresa').keyup(function() {

    var campo_nome_empresa = $("#campo_nome_empresa").val();
    var nomenome = ajustaNome(campo_nome_empresa);


    $("#campo_nome_empresa").val(nomenome);


  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Codigo para colocar apenas a primeira letra maiscula. Se a palavra tiver apenas duas letras, ela deverá continuar minúscula.<br><br> Exemplo, se a pessoa digitar:<br> - luis sanches de oliveira<br> - LUIS SANCHES DE LIVEIRA<br><br> o resultado será:<br>  - <b>Luis Sanches de Oliveira</b>
</p>

<input name="campo_nome_empresa" type="text" class="form-control input-md" id="campo_nome_empresa" maxlength="150">
```

Comment: Oi Anderson! Muito obrigado pelo suporte e explicação. =D Funcionou perfeitamente.